# SVN repository in /srv/subversion is owned by user apache and I don't have sudo - how to add/edit users?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions, svn, users

I'm working with an SVN repository on managed hosting for a client, using a login into the Linux server the client gave me. I don't think I can get root access as it's held by the managed hosting provider.

I see that the subversion repository is in /srv/subversion, but it's owned by the apache user and nobody seems to have its credentials. However, the managed hosting provider, presumably the one who would have the apache user's credentials, did not set up the repository! So, my questions are.

1. How was the SVN server originally installed such that the apache user ended up owning the repo?
2. How can I add/edit users to the SVN repo given that the conf subdirectory is locked away, owned by Apache (in Apache group) with 750 permission?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your hosting provider has some kind of web-based file manager available for you to use? For me it seems they use Apache and mod_php, so everything done from the web will be owned by apache user.

If they have some web file manager available, that way you can edit the files. Might be clunky, might be awkward, but should work.

My crystal ball tells me they use Webmin and [its file manager](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/FileManager), ask them if you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ask whoever setup the repository.
2. Obtain the necessary permissions.

This is, of course, assuming that the information you've provided is accurate and exhaustive.  I'm sure you've already checked for POSIX ACLs, for instance.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that there is absolutely no way I can admin this without either root or apache credentials?

Comment: Based on the information provided, the third option is having a permissions-breaking kernel exploit, but I'd say one of the first two would be easier to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

For apache typically the users are stored in a generic htpasswd file.  The apache directive is called `AuthUserFile` and I'd be surprised if they didn't have some kind of web interface to maange htpasswd files.  The config files are usually in /etc/httpd or /etc/apache2 but could be anywhere if the same box is hosting many domains.